# Самовызывающиеся функции и момент их инициализации

Tags: javascript

Из-за чего в коде ниже на момент выполнения самовызывающейся функции переменная f не определена? Ведь самовызывающиеся ф-и вроде как не поднимаются вверх по коду, как это происходит с записью аля "function x(){}".

```js
let f = function(x) {
  alert(x)
}

(function() {
  f(1)
}())
```

Comment: нужно точки с запятой ставить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из-за отсутствия `;` после `}` интерпретатор считает приведенный код не двумя независимыми блоками, а одним

```
let f = (function (){...})(function(){...}())
```

Таким образом самовызывающаяся функция считается параметром функции, которую присваивают в переменную `f`. И так как параметры вычисляются до вызова самой функции, выполнение самовызывающейся функции происходит **до** присвоения `f` какого либо значения.

Для решения достаточно расставить `;` на нужные места:

```js
let f = function(x) {
  alert(x)
};

(function() {
  f(1)
}())
```